# Using the ternary operator in php to echo different statuses based on an event status in sql

Tags: php, html, sql, css

Well if the status is 1 it's "Active Insurance Event" and if 2 it's "Completed Insurance Event".

```
if(!empty($ins_event))
            {
            echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;<img src='/check-icon.gif'> <a href='". matry::here(array('event_id'=>$ins_event['id'])) . "'>" . ( $ins_event['status'] == 2 ? "Completed Insurance Event": "Active Insurance Event") . "</a></td></tr>"; 
            }
else 
        {
        echo "<tr><td>" . cbox_return() . "<a href='". matry::here_to('new', array('tfilt'=>'IN', 'pfilt'=>$patient->code)) . "' style='color: #000; color:$rx_image_color'>**Ins Event Not Created**</td></tr>";
        }
```

I have a variable for color here:

```
<?php
$rx_event_colors = $rx_ev_status = '#009933';
?>
```

How can i use this variable to grab the status of 2 and change the font color.

Should i break up the script and use if {} else {} statements?

---

updated code:

```
echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;<img src='/check-icon.gif'> <a href='". matry::here(array('event_id'=>$ins_event['id'])) . "'" . ( $ins_event['status'] == 2 ? ' style="color: ' . $rx_ev_status . '">Completed Insurance Event' : '>Active Insurance Event') . "</a></td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would basically do the same kind of ternary operation:

```
($ins_event['status'] == 2 ? ' style="color: ' . $rx_ev_status . '"' : '')
```

Comment: it's not working but i feel it should be... I'm going to update my code above.

Comment: it worked, it was an error with my variable. thanks for the help.. it was greatly appreciated and i learned how to add styles inside of a string using the ternary operator . =]

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean? Your question isnt that clear..

```
if(!empty($ins_event))
            {
            echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;<img src='/check-icon.gif'> <a ".($ins_event['status'] == 2 ? 'style="color:'.$rx_ev_status.';"': '')." href='". matry::here(array('event_id'=>$ins_event['id'])) . "'>" . ( $ins_event['status'] == 2 ? "Completed Insurance Event": "Active Insurance Event") . "</a></td></tr>"; 
            }
```

Here is an edit with the echo broken out onto different lines for clarity...

```
echo '<tr><td>&nbsp;<img src="/check-icon.gif">';
echo '<a '.($ins_event['status'] == 2 ? 'style="color:'.$rx_ev_status.';"': '')." ";
echo ' href="'. matry::here(array('event_id'=>$ins_event['id'])) . '">'; 
echo ($ins_event['status'] == 2 ? 'Completed Insurance Event': 'Active Insurance Event');
echo '</a></td></tr>';
```

Comment: More confused with all the different echo's. Sorry, I appreciate the help but it seems more confusing like that.

Comment: Not sure how to help if you can't understand a single echo line being broken out into many lines.. perhaps a good read of php.net/manual is needed for further help. Though what specifically do you not understand with it being output on many lines?

Comment: sorry, it worked fine for me, i did a var dump and realized my string was empty and i was using the wrong variable.

Comment: Superb - glad its fixed. However I'm confused you accepted someone else's answer as the solution when my answer was before his / the same / I provided extra replies for clarity

Answer (score -2):

Yes, for performance and code maintenance reasons logic operations should be done as infrequently as possible. Set both the text status and color variables inside of a single `if { … } else { … }` block. After storing the status and colors to variables, you can simplify the `echo` statement greatly.

```
echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;<img src='/check-icon.gif'> <a href='". matry::here(array('event_id'=>$ins_event['id'])) . "'>$status</a></td></tr>";
```

I would also consider storing the output of `matry::here(…)` in a variable for even easier code reading.

Comment: _"Yes, for performance reasons logic operations should be done as infrequently as possible"_ - in a binary computer, what is cheaper than logic?

Comment: The OP's final code is using a single ternary statement, but the original question led me to believe he was planning to use two ternary statements: one for color, and another for text. If that were the case, the code would run slower than if he did the logic once and stored the results of the test in a variable or variables. Please see http://pastebin.com/mbXKvh1v for how I envisioned his question (function test0) and how I recommended he reformat his code for both performance and maintainability (function test1).